# Calling a FORTRAN subroutine from C

Tags: c, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I am trying to call a FORTRAN function from C

My questions are:

1. If `fortRoutine` is the name of my fortran subroutine, then I am calling this from C
   as `fortRoutine_`. If `fortRoutine` contains only one character array argument, then can I pass like this:

   ```
   fortRoutine_("I am in fortran");
   ```
2. While calling FORTRAN subroutines, when should I use pass by value and when pass by reference?

As I am new to C, I do not have a clue about this. If possible, please suggest some good tutorial links as well.

Comment: provide more info like platform/compiler since what you are asking is highly dependent on the platform.

Answer (score 30):

The way to do this now is to use the Fortran ISO C Binding on the Fortran side.   This is part of the Fortran 2003 language standard and is available in many compilers; it is not specific to gcc.  It has been described in many answers on this site.  As part of the language standard, it is compiler and platform independent.   And you do not need to know about the internal passing conventions of the compiler.  The ISO C Binding, when used in the declaration of a Fortran subroutine or function, causes the Fortran compiler to use the C calling conventions so that that procedure can be directly called from C.   You do not need to add hidden arguments or name mangle the Fortran subroutine name, i.e., no underscores.  The name used by the linker comes from the "bind" option.

Strings are a difficult case because technically in C they are arrays of characters and you have to match this in the Fortran.  You also have to deal with the different definitions of strings: C is null terminated, Fortran fixed length and padded with blanks.  The example shows how this works.  Numbers are easier.  The only issue with arrays is that C is row-major and Fortran column-major so that multi-dimensional arrays are transposed.

```
int main ( void ) {

   char test [10] = "abcd";

   myfortsub (test);

   return 0;

}
```

and

```
subroutine myfortsub ( input_string ) bind ( C, name="myfortsub" )

   use iso_c_binding, only: C_CHAR, c_null_char
   implicit none

   character (kind=c_char, len=1), dimension (10), intent (in) :: input_string
   character (len=10) :: regular_string
   integer :: i

   regular_string = " "
   loop_string: do i=1, 10
      if ( input_string (i) == c_null_char ) then
         exit loop_string
      else
         regular_string (i:i) = input_string (i)
      end if
   end do loop_string

   write (*, *) ">", trim (regular_string), "<", len_trim (regular_string)

   return

end subroutine myfortsub
```

You compile the C to an object file and use gfortran to compile the fortran and link both:

```
gcc-mp-4.6   \
         -c  \
         test_fortsub.c

gfortran-mp-4.6   \
     test_fortsub.o  \
     myfortsub.f90  \
     -o test_fortsub.exe
```

Output is:

```
 >abcd<           4
```

Comment: Generally this is the bust way, but I think, that many times, if a C programmer aks, they often really don't want to dig in their legacy FORTRAN 77 and older codes. It's then sometimes better to write a wrapper in C.

Comment: Or worse, don't have the luxury of `iso_c_binding`. Still, +1 this is the approach to take if you control it both (although I generally choose to manage the string stuff on the C-side, far simpler imho).

Answer (score 3):

Of course this all depends on your FORTRAN Compiler, but generally speaking:

1. No, you'll need to pass a hidden length argument for your string. Some compilers interleave these with the other parameters, directly after the string. Others, group all string length arguments at the end of the argument list.

   ```
   char str[11] = {0};
   fortranFunc_(str, sizeof(str) - 1);
   // remember that 'str' will need to be null terminated
   // and will be padding with spaces to fit the length
   // so for C passing strings to Fortran specify the length
   // less 1 so you can add a nul terminator, and on all strings
   // being filled in by FORTRAN, trim-end all spaces.
   ```
2. Almost always it is pass by reference, but you can toggle this behavior using attributes on the dummy arguments on the FORTRAN side.

   ```
   int value = 10;
   fortranFunc_(&value);
   // INTEGER I
   ```

Here are some references, which are applicable based on various compilers:

- [FORTRAN/C interoperability](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/ch1-11.html)
- [gfortran - Interoperability with C](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Interoperability-with-C.html)
- [Intel Fortran - Interoperability with C](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/compilerpro/en-us/fortran/lin/compiler_f/bldaps_for/common/bldaps_interopc.htm)
- [The ISO_C_BINDING module](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlf101l.doc%2Fxlflr%2Finterop-iso-c-binding-module.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends upon the compiler and the system (technically, its ABI). For GCC (which is a C, a C++, an Ada, and a Fortran compiler) read the [fortran mixed programming](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gfortran/Mixed_002dLanguage-Programming.html#Mixed_002dLanguage-Programming) chapter.