# How to bind C's char** argument in Fortran?

Tags: c, binding, fortran

I need to bind a C function in Fortran. The C function's prototype is something like

```
/* If argv[i] is NULL, then i is the length of argv[] */
int foo(char* argv[]);
```

I want to call foo in a Fortran subroutine bar

```
! If argv(i) is a blank string, then i is the length of argv.
! Constant MAX_STRING_LEN is the maximal length of any possible element in argv.
subroutine bar(argv) 
  character(len=*), intent(in) :: argv(*)

  character(kind=c_char), dimension(*), allocatable :: argv_c(*) !???

  ! convert argv to argv_c element by element, something like
  ! allocate(argv_c(len_trim(argv(i)) + 1) ! Plus 1 to put C_NULL_CHAR
  ! assign argv(i) to argv_c(i)

  ierror = foo(argv_c)
  ! deallocate each argv_c(i)
end subroutine bar
```

I want to know how to declare a prototype for foo. I designed this one, but I am not sure if it is correct. Is this argv interoperable with char**?

```
function foo(argv) bind(c, name="foo")
    character(kind=c_char), dimension(*), intent(in) :: argv(*)
end function
```

Comment: So, from the context of your quesiton, it appears you are asking how to _translate_ C style functions into FORTRAN style functions.  Ts this correct?

Comment: You have two times declared the dimension of `argv`.

Comment: Not translate C into Fortran, but calling C in Fortran.

Comment: @JunchaoZhang -  Yes, I see that.  My mistake, I have already edited my answer below, and have included some links I hope will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Similar question and answer: [Creating a FORTRAN interface to a C function that returns a char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972743/creating-a-fortran-interface-to-a-c-function-that-returns-a-char)  Little bit difficult to orient in there (at least for me).

You must pass pointer to the array, because of the `char**`

```
function foo(argv) bind(c, name="foo")
    type(c_ptr) :: argv  !note no `value` here
                         ! what is the `intent` to put here?
end function
```

The normal array argument would pass just a `char*` which you do not want.

First try:

```
ierror = foo(c_loc(argv_c))
```

The above would work if the C part does not allocate it, which it probably does. The problem is then to get the length of the string.

```
type(c_ptr) :: argv_c_ptr
character(kind=c_char),pointer :: argv_c(:)

ierror = foo(argv_c_ptr)
```

Now you must find out length of the array, I would call C procedure strlen (see C_strlen in http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/c_interface_module). After that you can call:

```
call c_f_pointer(argv_c_ptr, argv_c, [len])
```

Do not forget to deallocate the C allocated string properly, do not use Fortran `deallocate for that.

Comment: I see. argv_c in Fortran must be an array of c_ptr. And for each arv_c(i), I need to do dynamic memory allocation to copy argv(i) to argv_c(i) and put the NULL character. That is horrible.

Comment: No `argv_c` is not an array of `c_ptr's`, it is an `c_ptr` pointer to an array. But again, it is not clear form your code, what does the c-procedure actually does? I supposed it allocates the string. Also note I just corrected an error in my code.

Comment: I mean, if it just accepts the string from Fortran, you can just do the `foo(c_loc(argv_c))`.

Comment: the C function just reads the input argv, and does other things. In other words, I want Fortran to allocate temp memory and prepare argv_c in a good shape before calling C.

Comment: In that case use my prototype, call using c_loc(argv_c)  and use the code in your question for allocating, it is quite simple. But the char** for just reading is strange.

Answer (score 2):

The C declaration `char *argv[]` is array of pointer to char.  The equivalent Fortran argument declaration is `TYPE(C_PTR) :: argv(*)`, where each element in the array is the C address of a character of C kind.

The usual C convention is that the character is actually the first character in an array of character (i.e. you have the C address of an array of character of C kind), and the length of that array of char is null terminated (i.e. all up you have an array of pointers to C strings).  The comment in your C code also indicates that the size of the array of pointers is indicated by a final array element of NULL.  This is consistent with the conventions around `argv` arguments in C.

To be able to find the C address of an object in Fortran, the object must have the TARGET attribute.  The results of evaluating an expression does not have the target attribute.

As written, the `bar` subroutine has no idea about the size of the `argv` dummy array (it is an assumed size argument).  However, if the `argv` dummy argument was perhaps assumed shape, you could do something like:

```
SUBROUTINE bar(argv)
  USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_LOC, C_CHAR, C_INT,  &
      C_NULL_CHAR, C_NULL_PTR
  ! The input to bar (?) that needs to be converted for use in the C function.
  CHARACTER(*), INTENT(IN) :: argv(:)
  ! The array of C pointers.
  TYPE(C_PTR) :: argv_c(SIZE(argv) + 1)
  ! A local type to simplify memory management.
  TYPE string
    CHARACTER(LEN=:,KIND=C_CHAR), ALLOCATABLE :: item
  END TYPE string
  ! Temporary arrays of character.  Need to have TARGET for C_LOC.
  TYPE(string), TARGET :: tmp(SIZE(argv))
  ! Utility index.
  INTEGER :: i                    

  ! The interface for the C function
  INTERFACE
    FUNCTION foo(argv) BIND(C, NAME='foo')
      USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_PTR, C_INT
      IMPLICIT NONE
      ! INTENT(IN) here assuming foo doesn't modify the array of pointers.
      TYPE(C_PTR), INTENT(IN) :: argv(*)
      INTEGER(C_INT) :: foo
    END FUNCTION foo
  END INTERFACE

  INTEGER(C_INT) :: ierror

  DO i = 1, SIZE(argv)
    ! This may involve kind conversion.
    tmp(i)%item = TRIM(argv(i)) // C_NULL_CHAR
    argv_c(i) = C_LOC(tmp(i)%item)
  END DO
  ! Size of the argv array on the C side indicated by a NULL.
  argv_c(SIZE(argv_c)) = C_NULL_PTR

  ierror = foo(argv_c)
  ...

  ! memory allocated for the components of the tmp object (and hence 
  ! the things pointed at by the argv_c array) will go away when this 
  ! subroutine terminates.
END SUBROUTINE bar
```

Comment: Thanks to @IanH. Your explanation is amazing. I think Fortran textbooks should add this char** case, instead of just talking about char*. Since char** is common, and it is very different from passing char*.  BTW, in my case, argv is assume-sized, because the interface designer thought the callee can decode argv's length by looking for a blank line.

Comment: Note that what's appropriate for `char **` depends on the nature of the thing being pointed to.  The comments in the code in your question (and the name of the argument) suggest the approach in this answer - it may not always be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The standard does not provide an easy way to write a Fortran interoperable routine that accepts a string from C. You must declare the dummy argument as an array of single characters. You can use the combination of the C_LOC and C_F_POINTER procedures, both defined in intrinsic module ISO_C_BINDING, to "cast" a character array argument to a Fortran pointer to a character string. An example follows:

```
subroutine Interop_sub(arg) BIND(C)
USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING
CHARACTER, DIMENSION(*) :: ARG
CHARACTER(1000), POINTER :: LCL_ARG ! Local pointer to argument 
CALL C_F_POINTER(C_LOC(ARG), LCL_ARG)
```

From ***HERE(http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/fortran-mac/GUID-ECF6FF36-1397-43D8-88BB-CCD2F6108DA5.htm)***

***[HERE](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Interoperability-with-C.html)*** is an additional link for BIND(C)

There are also some translation concepts (C to FORTRAN and visa versa) ***[HERE](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialMixingFortranAndC.html)*** if you can use them